# What is the equivalent condition for a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be well-defined as a smooth function on $S^{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The question is as in the title.

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth and bounded function. What would be the necessary and sufficient condition for this $f$ to be extended to a smooth function on $S^{n}$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I presume that $f$ must show some consistent asymptotic behavior at infinity, but cannot formulate it in precise wording.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: A small point, but the one-point compactification of ${\Bbb R}^n$ is $S^n$.

Comment: Oops....... I will change this.

Comment: Your question is not even as in the title, because it has an implicit and false presupposition, namely that the smooth structure on $\mathbb R^n$ ***uniquely*** extends to a smooth structure on the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$. There are in fact many, many inequivalent extensions. A function which is smooth with respect to one of those extensions will fail to be smooth with respect to every other extension.